# Карта с автоматически проложенным маршрутом

Tags: веб-программирование, google-maps-api, yandex-maps-api, карты, геолокация

Создать отметку на карте, проложить до нее маршрут от определенной точки - не создает трудностей.

Интересует следующая возможность: пользователь заходит на сайт, нажимает на ссылку "Схема проезда" или "Карта проезда" (не суть), ему открывается страница с картой и проложенным маршрутом от его текущего местоположения до заданной точки (магазина, например). Естественно, если человек находится за 2000 км - это не имеет особого смысла. А вот если он находится в черте города, ну или если за его пределами (тут можно указать маршрут из ближайшей  от пользователя въездной точки в город).

Так как (и если вообще можно) это реализовать?

На вскидку приходит вариант отслеживания текущего положения пользователя, перенос координат позиционирования в API конструктора карт и построение маршрута.

UPD: Только вот не совсем понятно, как осуществить передачу координат в API конструктора.

Comment: А в чём именно проблема? Алгоритм построения маршрута умеет строить маршрут из точки _A_ в точку _B_. Для вашего случая _A_ := _текущее местоположение_, _B_ := _магазин_.

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, как "скармливать" координаты в API.

Comment: О. Вот в этом-то и состоит ваш вопрос, по сути. Может быть, внесёте в текст?

Comment: Минутка рекламы: воспользуйтесь http://api.2gis.ru/, там это реализовано уже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

objectPosition – координаты Вашего магазина,
'#map' – id контейнера карты.

Будет построен оптимальный маршрут, если расстояние меньше 2000км. Если нужны транзитные точки, то их можно добавить в массив routePoints.

Используется Yandex API 2.1.

```
ymaps.ready(function() {
    var objectPosition = [55.869376, 37.283022],
        map = new ymaps.Map('#map', {
            center: objectPosition
        });

    ymaps.geolocation.get({
        autoReverseGeocode: true
    }).then(function (result) {
        var userPosition = result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates(),
            routePoints = [objectPosition, userPosition];

        ymaps.route(routePoints, {
            mapStateAutoApply: true
        }).then(function (route) {
            if (route.getLength() < 2000000) {
                map.geoObjects.add(route);
            } else {
                map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Placemark(userPosition));
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Для передачи в приложение можно использовать ссылку на карту с заданной одной точкой в

```
https://maps.yandex.ru/213/moscow/?ll=<*map coords*>&z=15&rtext=~<*marker coords*>&rtt=mt
```

Но тут есть проблемы (во всяком случае у меня на андроиде): маршрут строится из этой точки до моего местоположения, а не до точки от меня. Если кто найдет, как можно в приложения передавать именно конечную точку маршрута, буду рад услышать.

Для браузера у меня автоматом местоположение не подхватывается. Но если запрашивать его перед переходом, то можно добавлять в ссылку перед `~`.

**UPDATE:**
Добавил получение текущих координат:
    ymaps.ready(function()
    {

```
    ymaps.geolocation.get(
        {
            autoReverseGeocode: false,
            provider: 'browser'
        }).then(function (result) {
        var userPosition = result.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates();
        document.getElementById('map-link').href = 'https://maps.yandex.ru/213/moscow/?ll=/*координаты карты*/&z=15&rtext=' + userPosition[0] + ',' + userPosition[1] + '~/*координаты конечной точки*/&rtt=mt';
    });
})
```

В итоге, если удалось получить координаты, делаю ссылку на маршрут, если не удалось, то просто оставляю без изменений ссылку на точку.